# Always show all paths and anchors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Its very annoying that when I'm doing something like tracing and image, the paths and anchors don't show on the screen unless selected.  A common issue is I'm tracing an image that is in a background layer, and I have to do a bunch of line joins, but can't see the anchors.  Or I delete and anchor, but it deletes everything since I, `ctrl-a` 'd everything so I could see what I was working.  `ctrl-y` doesn't work, cuz it won't show the background image.  I would just prefer to see everything all the time, whether its selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to show anchor points when not selected. Anchor points are not objects that you can color or mark (except manually which is not worth doing)- they are more just coordinates.

Obviously you can show the paths by merely setting a stroke color.

I cannot come up with even a workaround for this- taking a screenshot of your selected paths and then adding that as a template layer with reduced opacity ? Not at all a feasible alternative.

There are a couple settings in Preferences that could assist ( Illustrator> Preferences> Selection and Anchor Display).

[image]

The "Highlight Anchor Points on Mouse Over" will show when you are over a path or an anchor with a selection tool or with the pen tool.

The "Snap To Point" (with max 8 px setting) will help you snap to anchor points (even when not selected) but this helps more with moving objects than when drawing objects.

It will also make a difference with what drawing tool you may be using (you did not identify)- you say "tracing an image" and I assume you mean manually and not with Image Trace. It could be a matter of using the proper tool. Pen Tool and Anchor Point Tool would seem the best bet- Not sure what your method is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want everything visible all the time. It would quickly become unmanageable. I think this is *far more* a workflow issue than anything.

Manual tracing is a special workflow that requires an understanding of how to create things so you can see them, but not block the underlying template.

For example, I tend to lay down paths set at a .25pt stroke in 100% magenta. Then after *all* the paths are drawn I go back and adjust fils and strokes. Adding fills/strokes *as you trace* often created hurdles because underlying visuals are covered up. Simply don't cover anything until you've drawn all the paths.

Wise usage of layers can assist as well. Allowing you to turn off visibility for layers.